# Image is not loading on page

Tags: python, django, django-templates

my image file is not loading in webpage it is showing **The 'Img' attribute has no file associated with it**

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    Img = models.ImageField(null =True, blank = True, upload_to='static/images')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from portfo import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
     path('',  views.firstpage,name='firstpage'),
    path('', include('portfo.urls')),
    path('admin/',  admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
    ]
MEDIA_URL ="/images/"
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/images')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

template

```
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body " style="background-color: #F2F4F3;">
                    <img src="{{post.Img.url}}" /> 
                    <h2 class="card-title" style="margin-left:40% ;">{{ post.title|capfirst }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}...</p>
                    <a href="/{{post.slug}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

I have a file name images inside the static. Your help is much appriciated

Comment: How are you adding the data to the model? Can you verify from Django shell if the image file is accessible in the entry?

Comment: Yes the name of the image is showing but when i add ({{post.Img.url}}) because of  .url addition it shows this error

Comment: Is the file URL visible on Django admin? Can you access the file from admin?

Comment: yes the url is visible and i can access it from admin